# IE7 float (not div's)

Tags: internet-explorer-7, css-float

I wanted to make simple form, without awesome div's and CSS - it structure is like:

```
<form id="cform" action="/" method="post">
<fieldset>
<label class="first" for="name">Nazwa firmy: </label><input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
<label class="first" for="email">Email: </label><input id="email" name="email" type="text" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS

```
#cform input, #cform textarea, #cform label, #cform select
{
float: left;
}
label.first, #cform input[type="submit"]
{
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 150px;
float: left;
clear: both;
}
#cform textarea
{
width: 400px;
height: 250px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

In FF, IE8, Chrome and Opera it looks good. But in IE7 inputs are looking, like they don't have float at all. How to fix it? (version without adding divs please)

Aww, forgot link
http://site.amm.siedlce.pl/front/page/get/79/

Comment: Have you considered using an IE7-specific stylesheet and call it by using conditional comments?

Comment: But I don't even know how to fix it in IE7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 doesn't support the attribute selector, `input[type="submit"]`.

Reference them by class.